# Sellenium/Jest - Run concurrent tests in new chrome window using the same session

Tags: node.js, selenium-webdriver, jestjs, automated-tests

We use a low code platform and currently working on to testing using Sellenium Webdriver and Jest in nodejs.

In the development environment we need to first authenticate and make a site release before we can actually run any tests on the test release.
In our current testing architecture we are building a new driver for each test and doing authentication and release with every test and that is not really good approach in terms or time and resource usage. However, what we are trying to implement is to only authenticate and release once and run all the test cases within the same session. We have implemented the working solution without the concurrency however we would like to achieve concurrency for faster execution.

The below code works fine without achieving any concurrency

```
describe("Test-Suite", () => { 
    let product; 
    let originalWindow; 
    beforeAll(async () => { 
    const driver = new Builder().forBrowser(Browser.CHROME).build(); 
    await authticateAndReleaseSite(driver); 
    product = new Product(driver); 
    originalWindow = await driver.getWindowHandle(); });
    
    
    
    afterAll(async () => {
        product.driver.quit();
    });
    
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await product.driver.switchTo().newWindow("window");
    });
    
    afterEach(async () => {
        await product.driver.close();
        await product.driver.switchTo().window(originalWindow);
    });
    
    test.each(testCases)("$testcase", async () => {
        // tests for product
    });
});
```

However what we would like to achieve is concurrency using test.concurrent which seems not to be possible using jest as test.concurrent does not wait for beofreAll to run. Github issue [here](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/4281)

`test.concurrent.each(testCases)("$testcase", async () => {     // tests });`

We have tried some other approaches such as trying to copy the sellenium session into a new driver or adding manual waits before starting the test process within the test case, but nothing worked precisely.
Any workarounds would be appreciated

Comment: Best practice is to create a new driver for each test and dispose of it in the end. This gives you the cleanest run possible, avoiding cross-contamination of tests. I would strongly suggest you not abandon this. Also, it gives you the ability to run tests in parallel which significantly speeds the overall runtime of the suite. Running all tests in a single browser is not only going to be much more complicated, it's also going to significantly slow your suite runtime. Both of which you seem to be experiencing already.

Comment: What does, "doing authentication and release with every test" mean? How does that slow down your tests or use more resources?

Comment: @JeffC we use a low code web platform something similar to wordpress, and would require to do a test publish site before testing any development changes which is a time consuming process. As the number of tests are in hundreds when running functional testing, time adds up.

Comment: So create a hidden (non-public) version of the site, push all the changes for the new release, and then use the URL for the test site to drive your tests. Once the tests have passed, push the test site to the public site. I guess I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: @JeffC currently we are using the same approach as you said, but it does not meet all our requirements.
All I want to know here is if it is possible to share sessions between drivers or run the parallel tests using the same driver.

Comment: There's no way to share sessions between drivers and it's one driver per browser instance.